# How to use mod_rewrite to change this url http://outis-music.com/#url=http%3A//outis-music.com/podcast-2/?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I need to change urls like this one `http://outis-music.com/#url=http%3A//outis-music.com/podcast-2/` to eliminate this part `/#url=http%3A//outis-music.com`

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

untested code, however you are just running a regular expression search and replace on the url string.

```
RewriteRule (\/#url=http%3A\/\/outis\-music.com)$ [L]
```

**good reading:**

-[mod_rewrite sytax](http://www.webforgers.net/mod-rewrite/mod-rewrite-syntax.php)

-[Regex Reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

Comment: I have had to get rid of a ajax plugin causing wron url to be created...however the answer was right and worked; unlucly for me I have had to quit using ajax on that site for now...